# Newton's method, second partials tend to 0?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was reading section 2.8 on Newton's method of Hubbard's Vector Calculus,Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms. At the end of this section, it is stated that:

If the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2...$ converges to a root, the number obtained by squaring the second partials (evaluated at the point $a_0$ ( and then at $ a_1,a_2...)),$ adding them together,and taking the square root of the sum ,steadily decreases and tends to $ 0$.

Why does this sequence of numbers steadily decrease and tend to $0$?

Comment: It sounds like you are considering the sum $(f''(a_0))^2+(f''(a_1))^2+\dots+(f''(a_n))^2$. This cannot tend to zero for $n\to\infty$ because generally all terms are positive. Probably I misunderstood your question, can you clarify which expression you are talking about?

Comment: The number is the square root of the sum of the square of second order partial derivatives :$(\sum_{1\le i,j \le n}(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(a_0))^2)^\frac{1}{2}$. The sequence is this number evaluated at $a_0, a_1$...

Comment: That makes more sense, but then the statement is not true in general. Counterexample: dimension $n=1$, function $f(x)=x^2-1$ starting point $a_0=1$. Then $a_1=a_2=a_3=\dots=1$ (because $1$ is already a root). But $f''(a_n)=2$ for all $n$, so it does not tend to zero.